# Print blank exception in python

Tags: python

I am trying to figure out how I would print an exception if I don't know what the exception is in the first place. How would I do the following?

```
try:
    some_command
except:
    print *full_exception_trace*
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def exception(self)
    try:
        Something.objects.all()
    except Exception, err:
        print err.message #(if you want)
        #raise err
        raise # The 'raise' statement with no arguments inside an error
              # handler tells Python to re-raise the exception with the 
              # original traceback intact
```

err.message will give you the reason of the exception

Comment: I agree with the answer, but to nitpick: In most cases I would recommend you don't `raise err`, but instead just `raise`.  The former will cause a traceback to point to the `raise err` line; the latter will cause the traceback to point to the place the exception was originally raised.  A minor detail, but it can make a big difference in ease of debugging.

Answer (score 6):

[Like the tutorial says.](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions)

```
try:
  something()
except SomeException as e:
  something_else(e)
```

You may find [`traceback`](http://docs.python.org/library/traceback.html) useful.

Answer (score 1):

The `traceback` module's `print_exc()` function seems to be what you want. [Docs](http://docs.python.org/library/traceback.html)